# crie um programa que inverte os números com uso do while, mas meu programa sempre vai ignorar o 0 no final, como posso resolver?

Tags: python

```
def inverte(n):
    sequência = ''
    while n > 0:
        digito_invertido =  n % 10
        n //= 10
        sequência += str(digito_invertido)
    return sequência

def main():
    n = int(input())
    print(inverte(n))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- exemplo : `01234567890`
- retorno esperado: `9876543210`
- retorno que sai : `0987654321`

Comment: Mostre um exemplo de uma entrada e o resultado obtido que você considera que está sendo calculado errado.

Comment: Salvo n = 0, que obviamente não entra no while, qual outro inteiro (positivo) está dando errado?

Comment: exemplo: 0123456890 deveriam retornar 09876543210, só que está retornando 0987654321, ignorando o 0 no final da sequência

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está confundindo um número (um valor numérico) com a sua representação (uma string/texto que representa este número).

Por exemplo, o número 2 é só um "conceito", uma ideia: ele representa uma determinada quantidade, um valor numérico ("duas coisas"). Mas eu posso representar esse valor de vários jeitos diferentes: como o dígito `2`, ou como `2.0`, `2,00000`, `002`, `"dois"`, `"two"`, e de muitas outras maneiras - estes textos são diferentes, mas todos representam o mesmo número (o mesmo valor numérico).

Sendo assim, quando o usuário digita `01234567890` e este texto é passado para `int`, o resultado é o número `1234567890`, veja:

```
print(int('01234567890')) # 1234567890
```

Isso porque, ao transformar uma string para número, os zeros à esquerda não fazem diferença no valor final.

E ao inverter o número `1234567890` usando a sua função, o resultado é `0987654321` - mas isso acontece porque você está concatenando os dígitos em uma string, por isso o zero aparece no começo.

Se você tivesse usado somente matemática em vez de concatenar strings, o resultado seria apenas `987654321`. Ou seja, se fosse assim:

```
def inverte(n):
    sequência = 0
    while n > 0:
        digito_invertido =  n % 10
        n //= 10
        sequência = sequência * 10 + digito_invertido
    return sequência
```

O resultado seria `987654321`, afinal, para números, o zero à esquerda é irrelevante.

---

Então você precisa decidir o que quer inverter: a exata string que foi digitada pelo usuário (com zeros à esquerda e tudo mais) ou o valor numérico correspondente ao que foi digitado (vale lembrar que o algoritmo só funciona para números positivos, mas vamos assumir que números negativos "não valem").

O mesmo vale para o resultado: deve ser uma string (possivelmente com zeros à esquerda) ou o valor numérico?

Se o usuário digitar "0012", isso equivale ao número 12, então se inverter o resultado deve ser `21` (pois estou invertendo o valor numérico, que é `12`) ou `2100` (pois eu inverti a exata string que foi digitada)?

E se digitar "1200", o resultado é `0021` (pois é a string que corresponde ao inverso) ou apenas `21` (é o valor numérico que corresponde a `0021`)?

No seu caso, parece que você quer considerar os zeros à esquerda da entrada (ou seja, quer inverter a string, não o valor numérico correspondente) e desconsiderar na saída (ou seja, pega a string invertida e transforma em número) - então daria para fazer assim:

```
n = input() # se for digitado "01234567890"
print(int(n[::-1])) # 9876543210
```

Ou seja, primeiro eu inverto a string que foi digitada ([usando a sintaxe de *slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931092)). Se for digitado "01234567890", a string invertida será `"09876543210"`, e depois ao passar isso para `int` o resultado será o número `9876543210`. Nem precisa fazer as contas, pois estou invertendo a string e só no final eu vejo se é um número.

Claro, se quiser verificar se realmente é um número antes de fazer a inversão, também pode:

```
n = input()
try:
    int(n) # verifica se foi digitado um número
    print(int(n[::-1])) # 9876543210
except ValueError:
    print('digite um número válido')
```